# Need ansible inventory file details

Tags: ansible

Could someone please help me to write ansible inventory file to connect to bitbucket - clone a file and place into ansible machine.

Playbook

```
---
- hosts: bitbucketURL
  tasks:
    - git:
        repo: https://p-bitbucket.com:5999/projects/VIT/repos/sample-playbooks/browse/hello.txt
        dest: /home/xxx/demo/output/
```

Inventory file

```
[bitbucketURL]
p-bitbucket.com:5999

[bitbucketURL:vars]
ansible_connection=winrm
ansible_user=xxx
ansible_pass=<passwd>
```

I am getting error while using this playbook and inventory file

```
-bash-4.2$ ansible-playbook -i inv demo_draft1.yml

PLAY [bitbucketURL] *****************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] **************************************************************************************************************************************
fatal: [p-bitbucket.nl.eu.abnamro.com]: UNREACHABLE! => {"changed": false, "msg": "ssl: auth method ssl requires a password", "unreachable": true}
        to retry, use: --limit @/home/c55016a/demo/demo_draft1.retry

PLAY RECAP **************************************************************************************************************************************************
p-bitbucket.nl.eu.abnamro.com : ok=0    changed=0    unreachable=1    failed=0
```

Please help me write a proper inventory file with correct parameters

Comment: The error message indicates that bitbucket requires a password.

Answer (score 0):

You need no inventory at all. All you need to do is to set the play to execute on `localhost`:

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:
    - git:
        repo: https://p-bitbucket.com:5999/projects/VIT/repos/sample-playbooks/browse/hello.txt
        dest: /home/xxx/demo/output/
```

That said, URL should point to Git repository, not a single file (if `hello.txt` is a single file).